Ag-grid: custom filter component is visible from the beginning (after update to v31)
After update ag-grid (in Angular) from 28 to 31 we got not strange issue: custom filter component is visible by default and attached below grid.
We've implemented feature to restore filter settings after come back to grid's page.
We do it in simple way:
this.gridApi.setFilterModel(savedFilterModel) //data from localStorage
Now applied filter (but not opened yet!) is also visible below grid :/
We've tried to implement other simple custom component, but with the same effect.

This problem was reported on their GitHub:
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/8241
Issue is fixed on ag-grid's version 32.
